# Smooth Scrolling not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have been trying for a while to make smooth scrolling work on my bootstrap site. I have been researching different codes on this site and this is the one I stuck with, but it won't animate. I'm not sure if it is something as simple as the selector not being the right one, or what the issue could be.

Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top">
      <a href="index.html" id="navbarBrand" class="navbar-brand">Stages of Change Counseling</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#services" class="nav-link">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#approach" class="nav-link">Approach</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#commitment" class="nav-link">Commitment</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--navbarNav-->
    </nav>

    <main>
      <section id="home">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 px-0">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="img/lotus.jpg" alt="Lotus flower">
            </div><!--col-->
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-10 mx-auto">
              <p id="cta">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. .</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-10 mx-auto">
              <p class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div><!--col-->
          </div><!--row-->
        </div><!--container-->
      </section>
      
      <section id="about">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-5 offset-xl-1 col-12">
              <img src="img/portrait.jpg" alt="A portrait of myself wearing a mint sweater and a flower flower pattern scarf" class="img-fluid d-block mx-sm-auto">
            </div><!--col-->
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-10 mx-auto">
              <h1 class="header">About me</h1>
              <p class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              <br><br>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div><!--col-->
          </div><!--row-->

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-10 mx-auto">
              <p class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              <br><br>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div><!--col-->
          </div><!--row-->
        </div><!--container-->
      </section>
      
      <section id="approach">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h1 class="header">Approach</h1>
            </div><!--col-->
            <div class="col-12 px-0">
              <img src="img/staircase.jpg" alt="spiral staircase" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-10 mx-auto">
            <p class="main-text">By listening deeply to each client before me, I strive to be fully present without preconceptions. By listening with an open heart to each person’s struggles, I pull from a lifetime of experience. Assessing which approaches may begin a particular client’s process of mitigating suffering may result in collaborating to start with a behavioral assignment, a cognitive restructuring process, dialoging with internal parts to release deeply held pain, or simply offering compassionate presence. The unique interaction between each individual and myself will yield different proscriptive approaches each time, <b>I definitely do not use a one size fits all approach.</b> Since healing often comes from a place of deep inner peace, behavioral homework may involve forms of meditation or relaxation to enhance systemic de-stressing. 
            <br><br>
            For the client’s part, awareness that change takes <b>effort</b>, is of paramount importance. Whatever a person’s configuration of functioning, it can usually only be changed, like building a wall or taking down a wall, brick by brick. That’s why my practice is called Stages of Change. Each person’s readiness to change and ability to apply focused, persistent effort unfolds at their own pace. As a wonderful teacher of mine said, “A therapist has maps but the client has to sit in the driver’s seat and put their foot on the gas.”
            <br><br>
            Albert Ellis used to have client’s put a banana on a leash and pull it down a crowded New York street to inoculate clients to what others’ thought of them! While few would relish a behavioral assignment like that, observation of the flow of one’s thoughts, courage to feel difficult feelings or journaling may help one know oneself at a deeper level. Surprising oneself with new capabilities built by taking risks can be deeply empowering. 
            </p>
            </div><!--col-->
          </div><!--row-->
        </div><!--container-->
      </section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#navbarNav .navbar-nav li .nav-link").on('click', function(smooth) {

//set hash
var target = this.hash;

//prevent default clicking behavior
smooth.preventDefault();

//grab height of the navbar
var navOffset = $('#navbar').height();

//animate the scroll
return $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - navOffset
}, 600, function() {
    //add hash to the end of URL
  return window.history.pushState(null, null, target);
});
```

});

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/hailtothev612/pen/XWdOWQd

Comment: You can just add a CSS rule for that: `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` .

Comment: It doesn’t work on safari according to canIuse https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only reason why this codepen does't work is because You are using jQuery code but jQuery is not loaded on website.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After adding this code, scrolling is working just fine.

1. Make sure that jQuery is loaded before script.
2. Make sure that You are not using jQuery Slim (smaller version with less functionality) because it does not support animate() function.

**Always debug code (F12 in browser and Console tab) to find issue.**

```js
$("#navbarNav .navbar-nav li .nav-link").on('click', function(smooth) {

    //set hash
    var target = this.hash;
    
    //prevent default clicking behavior
    smooth.preventDefault();
    
    //grab height of the navbar
    var navOffset = $('#navbar').height();
    
    //animate the scroll
    return $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - navOffset
    }, 600, function() {
        //add hash to the end of URL
      return window.history.pushState(null, null, target);
    });
  });
```

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
   color: #B19BD9; 
}

#navbar {
    background: #B19BD9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top">
          <a href="index.html" id="navbarBrand" class="navbar-brand">Stages of Change Counseling</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#services" class="nav-link">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#approach" class="nav-link">Approach</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#commitment" class="nav-link">Commitment</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--navbarNav-->
        </nav>

        <main>
          <section id="home">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 px-0">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/lotus.jpg" alt="Lotus flower">
                </div><!--col-->
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-10 mx-auto">
                  <p id="cta">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. .</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-10 mx-auto">
                  <p class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div><!--col-->
              </div><!--row-->
            </div><!--container-->
          </section>
          
          <section id="about">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-5 offset-xl-1 col-12">
                  <img src="img/portrait.jpg" alt="A portrait of myself wearing a mint sweater and a flower flower pattern scarf" class="img-fluid d-block mx-sm-auto">
                </div><!--col-->
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-10 mx-auto">
                  <h1 class="header">About me</h1>
                  <p class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  <br><br>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div><!--col-->
              </div><!--row-->

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-10 mx-auto">
                  <p class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                  <br><br>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div><!--col-->
              </div><!--row-->
            </div><!--container-->
          </section>
          
          <section id="approach">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <h1 class="header">Approach</h1>
                </div><!--col-->
                <div class="col-12 px-0">
                  <img src="img/staircase.jpg" alt="spiral staircase" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-10 mx-auto">
                <p class="main-text">By listening deeply to each client before me, I strive to be fully present without preconceptions. By listening with an open heart to each person’s struggles, I pull from a lifetime of experience. Assessing which approaches may begin a particular client’s process of mitigating suffering may result in collaborating to start with a behavioral assignment, a cognitive restructuring process, dialoging with internal parts to release deeply held pain, or simply offering compassionate presence. The unique interaction between each individual and myself will yield different proscriptive approaches each time, <b>I definitely do not use a one size fits all approach.</b> Since healing often comes from a place of deep inner peace, behavioral homework may involve forms of meditation or relaxation to enhance systemic de-stressing. 
                <br><br>
                For the client’s part, awareness that change takes <b>effort</b>, is of paramount importance. Whatever a person’s configuration of functioning, it can usually only be changed, like building a wall or taking down a wall, brick by brick. That’s why my practice is called Stages of Change. Each person’s readiness to change and ability to apply focused, persistent effort unfolds at their own pace. As a wonderful teacher of mine said, “A therapist has maps but the client has to sit in the driver’s seat and put their foot on the gas.”
                <br><br>
                Albert Ellis used to have client’s put a banana on a leash and pull it down a crowded New York street to inoculate clients to what others’ thought of them! While few would relish a behavioral assignment like that, observation of the flow of one’s thoughts, courage to feel difficult feelings or journaling may help one know oneself at a deeper level. Surprising oneself with new capabilities built by taking risks can be deeply empowering. 
                </p>
                </div><!--col-->
              </div><!--row-->
            </div><!--container-->
          </section>
```

Comment: I was trying it out in my file where I attached jquery as per bootstrap's instructions. Am I missing something? Here's what I have loaded. It won't even jump to each section
``<!--jQuery-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>``

Comment: Go to *Settings* -> *JS* -> *Add External Scripts/Pens* and type `jquery` in the search bar. Select one from the list and it should work.

Comment: Check console for error. Maybe you are getting undefined $ error because script is loaded before jquery itself.

Comment: It does work on the codepen. What in the world? But on my index file there's no error on the console and I did add the jquery apparently, so I'm not sure what is going on. I can try pasting my whole code? @chojnicki

Comment: @vanessam6 but jquery is for sure loaded BEFORE this animating code? Remember that browser is parsing and executing code from start (up) to end (down).

Comment: @chojnicki so I cleared cache and looked at the console and I got this 

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (script.js:15)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)

Comment: I forgot to add that the error occurs when I click on the nav links

Comment: It's because You are using jQuery Slim which doesn't provide animate function. Simply use regular jquery from my answer. Also I updated my anser with info about Slim version.